# Is there a way to use multiple queries per flow in aws appflow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, integration, saas, datadog, amazon-appflow

I am using Amazon Appflow to transfer data between Datadog and AWS. Each appflow uses a query related to a single monitor in Datadog (such as a metric monitor, or an anomaly monitor). However, we have a huge amount of monitors in Datadog, and from my experimentation, multiple queries can't be used per appflow, so the only straightforward solution is to create the same amount of appflows as monitors in Datadog.

I do not see this as a very efficient solution, considering the amount of monitors being used. Is there any workaround to this dilemma? If there is a solution besides appflow I will be more than happy to learn about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to use the Datadog API to retrieve the data and then write a custom script to push the data into AWS.  You can use AWS services like Lambda, AWS Batch, or AWS Glue to push the processed data to your desired destination (e.g. S3 or Redshift). You could also potentially use AWS Step Functions to automate this process more cleanly.